# Converting Long to Date in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, date

I have a field that is a Long type which represents a date.  It is in YYYYMMDD format.  (Example 04/10/2018 is 20180410.)

How do I convert that Long to a Date type using ArcGIS Pro 2.1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Convert Time Field](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/convert-time-field.htm) tool to format your date field with ArcGIS Pro.